# is it safe to use javascript module pattern?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I've been using javascript module pattern for while.

I showed an example of a module pattern to one of my coworkers. He said that the following code can make a memory leak.

```
var test = (function(){

   var events = {
      // my functions go here
   }

   return {
     // return something
   }

}());
```

he said that since events variable is an object and i'm not setting null for it, it can cause a memory leak even if I set **null for test** later.

As far as I know, the above code snippet is okay because I'm not passing events around.

I need advices!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code is fine.  Memory leaks in closures happen when you have a reference to a DOM element, because of the circular reference (`foo` holds on to `element`, and `element` holds on to `foo`, so they can never be garbage collected):

```
function foo(element, a, b) {
    element.onlick = function(a, b) { /* uses a and b */ };
}
```

My source for this belief is [here](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Closures#Closures)

But others might know of another problem ...

Answer (score 0):

@moon - Why worry too much? How often is that code getting executuded between sittings? How many bytes are going to get lost? Then you have to consider the various browsers that will interperet and run your Javascript.

In short - concentrate your efforts elsewhere - then you get better rewards.

Comment: // um...I put that code sample not because I'm using that code. That's just an example as I mentioned on my post.

Comment: @moon - I just think that your efforts will be better served elsewhere. (BTW - Name from Enid Btyton - Folk of the far away tree)

Comment: // i appreciate and understand your intention here, but a memory leak is not something that I want to skip; concentrating my efforts elsewhere by leaving a known problem is a problem in my humble opinion

Comment: @moon - How big is that memory leak? A few bytes? Perhaps better to look at the server end and dish out some better cavar?

Comment: // as I mentioned...this is..just a sample snippet code. Let's assume that the above code causes a memory leak. If I keep using that on my all projects, that would be a problem. Again, I understand what you mean...but I'm a learner here.

Comment: @moon - You need to think about the number of browsers multiplied by operating systems by the amount of a leak. Perhaps they need to restart the bowser once a day! But would it be better to spend more effort on the back end to ensure that the person that feeds you will have a business tomoworrow

Comment: @Ed Heal - Rather than repeatedly saying not to worry, how about you confirm whether or not the code in the question actually will cause a memory leak? As far as I can see there is nothing wrong with that code and it won't leak anyway...

Comment: @nnnnn - It may leak - I do not know of the interals for the various browsers. Would it be more profitable to spent the effort on the backend?